# Remove Zoom Slider in Word 2011 Status Bar

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I need to remove the Zoom Slider in the Status Bar in Word 2011.

Normally, it looks like this:

[image]

When resizing the window, it blocks page numbers and word count, and there is a perfectly usable zoom facility at the top right.

[image]

Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qeZ4N.png)? How exactly is it overlapping page numbers and word count? Is your window 300px wide?

Comment: @slhk I do a lot of translation and editing, so I need at least two windows at a time side by side. I would happily leave the slider where it is if it would only stay put, but it slides over the page numbers if I shrink the windows

Comment: @slhck This is a brilliant edit! I have to ask, are you just grabbing those images and adding the shadow or is there an app for that? Either way, many thanks.

Comment: Oh, when you press `Cmd-Shift-4`, and then `Space`, you get a "Window" mode that automatically adds the shadows!

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using the OS-X version and I'm not sure if this will apply to it. In Windows, Office 2010, right-clicking on the status bar brings up a large list of items that can be added or removed from the status bar, including the zoom slider, by simply checking or unchecking the desired item(s).

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft failed to port this to the OS X version.

Comment: Ah, the old "Apple users only have 1 finger" idea, which is only slightly more offensive than the rest of the tech industry (except gaming boutique makers) assuming all users only have 2 or 3 fingers.